# vestal_versions and htmldiff question of reversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, versioning, vestal-versions, reversion

I'm guessing there's probably an easier way to do what I'm doing so that the code is less unwieldy.

I had trouble understanding how to use the revert_to method... i wanted something where i could call up two different versions at the same time, but this doesn't seem to be the way that vestal_versions works.

This code works, but I'm wondering if I'm making something harder than it needs to be and I'd like to find out before I delve deeper.

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])

if params[:versions]
  v = params[:versions].split(',')
  @article.revert_to(v.first.to_i)
  @content1 = @article.content
  @article.revert_to(v.last.to_i)
  @content2 = @article.content
end
```

In case you're wondering, I'm using this in conjunction with HTMLDIFF to get the version changes.

```
<div id="content">
  <% if params[:versions] %>
    <%= Article.diff(@content1, @content2) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= @article.content %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the `changes_between` method that vestal_versions provides.

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])

if params[:versions]
  v = params[:versions].split(',')
  @article_changes = @article.changes_between(v.first.to_i, v.last.to_i)
end
```

then `@article_changes` is a hash of the changes between the versions.  Something like

```
{"content" => ["first version content", "second version content"]}
```

Maybe different depending on what you have versioned.